# Scanner Class Java - reads too many input values

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

Here is my solution to Goldbach`s Conjecture problem for the numbers in the [m,n] interval. The code works but there is a problem with reading the values of a and m. Nothing happens if I do not introduce more than 2 input values ( like 4 or more). If I do so, the first value is assigned to m and the last one to n. Why is this happening? How can I correct it?

```
public class GoldbachConjecture {

    public static void Goldbach(int x) {
        int ok=0;
        for (int i = 3; i < x / 2 && ok==0; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i) && isPrime(x - i)) {
                System.out.println("The number is " + x + " Prime Numbers are " + i + " " + (x - i));
                ok=1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int x) {
        for (int i = 2; i < x / 2; i++) {
            if (x % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        System.out.print("Give the interval" );

        Scanner in1= new Scanner(System.in);
        int m = in1.nextInt();

        Scanner in2=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=in2.nextInt();

        for(int nr = m; nr <= n; nr++)
        {
         if(nr>2 && nr%2==0) 
              Goldbach(nr);
          } 
}
}
```

Comment: You don't need more than 2 numbers as input. You just can't enter them into the same line, due to your bad choice of using two independent `Scanner` instances.

Answer (score 1):

Firs of all, **you should use only one** `Scanner`. I think the problem lies in the fact that `Scanner.nextInt()` doesn't "consume" the `new line` character of your input (the one that you type when you hit enter in the terminal).

One workaround is calling `Scanner.nextLine()` after `Scanner.nextInt()`.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int m = sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine(); // consuming last new line.
```

**UPDATE:** You can try this workaround too (as seen in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13102066/4208583):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int m;
try {
    m = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: You can keep the first sentence, but the other stuff isn't correct here. There is no need to consume remaining line endings in OPs code.